# Best way to call a generic method multiple times (runtime return type) using a parameter-safe invocation

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, delegates

I feel like I'm so close to working this out and have read dozens of articles and existing questions.

I have a method like this:

```
public T DoStuff(object arg1, object arg2)
{
  /* Do stuff and return a T */
}
```

And I need to be able to pass this method to another class for callback purposes.
However, when this other class calls back it will do so with a different expected return type that is only known at runtime.

E.g.:

```
public void SomeMethod(MethodInfo m, ref object caller)
{
  MethodInfo callback = m.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { runtimeType });
  callback.Invoke(caller, new [] { arg1val, arg2val });
}

/* DoStuff() will make a call to SomeMethod() passing 
 * itself (the method and the object) */
```

However, instead of this I would like to be able to

1. Pass only a single callback object (i.e. a delegate or Func<>) to SomeMethod.
2. Be able to modify this object appropriately for the generic call.
3. Have type-safe parameters for the call as I would with a delegate/Func<>.

I've found approaches that suit each of these individually but none that covers all of them.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `MakeGenericMethod` usage, I assume that the method (in your example) is generic in `T`:

```
public T DoStuff<T>(object arg1, object arg2)
```

Given the amount of reflection you are doing, this simply isn't doing you any favors; for use from reflection you might as well use:

```
public object DoStuff(Type type, object arg1, object arg2)
```

And use (for example) `Activator.CreateInstance(type)` to create an instance. The above can now be used with a delegate; for example a `Func<Type,object,object,object>`.

Comment: Yeah you're right and good points. I feel dirty using this much reflection but I can't see another way of doing runtime parsing of data into arbitrary code objects. For a moment I was concerned about calling other generic methods as I wouldn't have an actual "T" type to work with but seeing as I'm calling them through reflection too this isn't a big issue and they can probably even be rewritten in a similar way to this. Thanks!